# A measure-equivalence class of measurable not null sets has a not empty intersection?

Tags: measure-theory

No explanations needed, title says all

Comment: If you take a partition of the set made with measurable sets all with the same measure, they all belong to the class of sets with the same measure but their intersection is empty.

Comment: If your measure is such that singletons have measure zero, then the sets $A$ with a singleton removed all belong to the same class as $A$, but their intersection is empty.

Comment: Even in your special case, consider any uncountable set with the sigma algebra of countable, co-countable sets, where countable sets are measure zero, and co-countable sets are measure 1.  Then the class of co-countable sets are a single atom.  But their intersection is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your measure is such that singletons have measure zero (for example, Lebesgue measure), then the sets which are $A$ with a singleton removed all belong to the same class as $A$, but their intersection is empty.

Even in your special case, consider any uncountable set with the sigma algebra of countable, co-countable sets, where countable sets are measure zero, and co-countable sets are measure 1. Then the class of co-countable sets are a single atom. But their intersection is empty.